# How do you turn on Amazon Music history?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

Recently my Amazon Music account stopped recording music played history.  I would like to be able to keep an eye on the music my daughters are playing.  I have looked all over and cannot find the setting to turn this on -- it used to be there until we added Echo Dots at Christmas.

[image]

Comment: Not sure such a history exists. There is a history of what anyone said for to the Echos in your account though.